# see if there is a match in the characters in one column and perform a function on its rows in R

Tags: r

So I am trying to find if there is any match with characters in one column of a dataframe and if it matches - I will be performing a function on its rows that has numerical values.
How can i achieve it in R

eg. dataframe

```
    A                    B      C    D
Hyper thread            760   85.49 889
Antihypertensive_drug   624   70.19 889
Strom practise          139   15.64 889
Antihypertensive_drug   44.8    67  29
```

if there is match of character "antihypertensive" then 
I will running a function on col. C and D  ----- `(sum(df$C,df$D))`

I tried using

the approximate match from plotmath

`a= which(df$A %~~% "antihypertensive")` and then use that as an index to run the sum function... but no luck any suggestions please

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you trying to sum per row, or just sum the whole thing for matched rows?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 indx <- grepl('antihypertensive', df$A, ignore.case=TRUE)
 with(df, ifelse(indx, C+D,NA))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Not a problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is unclear, if you only want `sum` per row, you can use `rowSums` or `Reduce`

```
indx <- grep('antihypertensive', df$A, ignore.case = TRUE) # borrowed this from @akrun
rowSums(df[indx, c("C", "D")])
#      2      4 
# 959.19  96.00
```

Or

```
Reduce(`+`, df[indx, c("C", "D")])
# [1] 959.19  96.00
```

Or you can sum the whole thing

```
sum(df[indx, c("C", "D")])
# [1] 1055.19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep to index rows.

```
whichRows <- grep("antihypertensive", dataframe[,1], ignore.case=TRUE)
```